# Text file , CVS xml or what are my options?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, windows-mobile, linq-to-objects

I want to develop an app for Windows 7 phone. It will be a GRE vocab app. i dont want to use SQL CE, my app will have 3 tables conceptually. I will be using Linq to SQL to querying data. Now i am confuse how should i store data so it is easy for retrival and update.

XML , CSV , XML or any other format ?

Comment: Was one of these answers helpful?  If so, can you mark one as the correct answer?  Otherwise, can you post how you did resolve this and mark that as the answer?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For such a simple database, I'd go with either XML or SQLite.  Both are queryable from code.

If you want to update external to the application, i.e. if you don't want to write an interface to update the vocabulary words, but would rather just open a file and update it manually, then XML is the way to go.

SQLite may be faster than querying XML (can't speak to this with certainty, but SQLite uses a binary format, which is generally faster), but you'd need to write all the screens to add words, update definitions, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Isolated Storage](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/05/06/windows-phone-7-development-using-isolated-storage.aspx) or [ready to use implementations](http://winphone7db.codeplex.com/).

Comment: what i understood from the Windows Phone 7 database project. is that there is default database installed which i can you use using Windows Phone 7 database api. is my understanding correct ?

Comment: @huzaifa: There is no "default database".  There is isolated storage, which is somewhat like a file system.  The database project uses that for storage.

Answer (score 0):

You can [use Perst](http://mobileworld.appamundi.com/blogs/andywigley/archive/2010/06/07/perst-a-database-for-windows-phone-7-silverlight.aspx) as a data store.  I also know that [SQLite](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/) also works, but I also hear that it's painfully slow.